# Regex-based string re-mapping in R dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I'm trying to clean messy free-form-captured strings in some dataframes by looping through regular expressions defined in other dataframes. For example:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
text <- c(NA, "messy1 messy2", "MESSY2,,, messy1", "ignore")
df <- data.frame(id, text)

mapin <- c("messy1", "messy2")
mapout <- c("Clean 1", "Clean 2")
map <- data.frame(mapin, mapout)

cout <- c(NA, "Clean 1, Clean 2", "Clean 1, Clean 2", NA)
```

I want to create the new column `df$cout` by regex'ing the matching tokens in `map$mapin` (ignoring case), and outputting corresponding cleaned tokens from `map$mapout` in a concatenated string, where the *output* tokens are sorted by alphabetical order. It seems to me that copy/regex-substitute on the messy dataframe column would be more pain that it's worth, because all the other non-matching stuff will have to be discarded somehow.

Can anyone see a good *R* / *vectorised* / *not-hammy* way of doing this?

Comment: Your output tokens contain spaces in them? It's not very clear how those should be sorted.

Comment: You won't need regular expressions necessarily, as your examples are all fixed text. Have you tried iterating with `gsub`? Also, your `cout` implies other cleaning/standardizing actions such as adding or single-ifying commas.

Comment: @David: Yeah, some do, some don't. In this case though, I'm actually sorting for _consistency_ of output (so the same set of input tokens will yield the same set of output tokens, irrespective of order). So it's just to make it easier to human reviewers that set1 == set2.

Comment: @r2evans: There's indeed not a lot of regex complexity in this example; I simplified for the question here. I had looked at iterating with gsub, but because half my problem here is a "wheat from chaff" of the infinite variation of what users type when confronted with free-form text, it seemed long-term easier to extract valid tokens only, rather than try to substitute in-place. Because, indeed, that would leave me with other cleaning/standardisation to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stri_extract_all` from the `stringi`-package:

```
library(stringi)
m1 <- sapply(map$mapin, function(x) stri_extract_all_fixed(tolower(df$text), x))
m2 <- matrix(map$mapout[match(m1, map$mapin)], ncol = nrow(map))

vec <- apply(m2, 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ", ") )
vec[vec == ''] <- NA

df$cout <- vec
```

you get:

```
> df
  id             text             cout
1  1             <NA>             <NA>
2  2    messy1 messy2 Clean 1, Clean 2
3  3 MESSY2,,, messy1 Clean 1, Clean 2
4  4           ignore             <NA>
```

Comment: stringi: Where have you been all my life!? Thanks Jaap!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Jaap's great answer, with a few tweaks that came up in my problem domain, but which could be common to others' challenges:

1. Dynamically determine the size of the map when creating matrix `m2`.
2. Sort the output tokens consistently.
3. Use `stri_extract_first_fixed` to be insensitive to duplicated input tokens.

Full example:

```
# Problem
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4) 
text <- c(NA, "messy1 messy2", "MESSY2,,, messy1,messy1", "ignore")
df <- data.frame(id, text)
mapin <- c("messy2", "messy1")
mapout <- c("Clean 2", "Clean 1")
map <- data.frame(mapin, mapout)

# Solution
m1 <- sapply(map$mapin, function(x) stri_extract_first_fixed(tolower(df$text), x))
m2 <- matrix(map$mapout[match(m1, map$mapin)], ncol = nrow(map))
vec <- apply(m2, 1, function(x)
    paste0(c(unique(sort(x, na.last = NA)), use.names = FALSE), collapse = ", "))
vec[vec==''] <- NA
df$clean <- vec
```

Per @r2evans' comment above, if you have a regular expression need here, just replace `stri_extract_first_fixed` with `stri_extract_first_regex`.